# C# mongodb parsing "+" - Quantifier{x,y} following nothing

Tags: c#, regex, mongodb

I am getting the above error when trying to search a field in mongodb collection using C# driver.

Below is the line of code where i am getting this error:

```
            IMongoQuery query = Query.Matches(field, BsonRegularExpression.Create(
                            new Regex(searchCri, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)));
```

I tried replacing the `searchCri` variable with `Regex.Replace(searchCri, "[~#%&*{}/<>?|\"-]+", "")` however it did not fix my problem.

Could anyone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because the `searchCri` starts with `+` or is following a non-quantifiable subpattern.

You need to implement [`Regex.Escape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx) and use something like:

```
new Regex(Regex.Escape(searchCri), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: great, thanx! Works perfectly.